# Removing $ from price in Postgres and calculating average

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am sorry for the dumb question, and i bet there is a solution somewhere but i couldn't quite catch it.
Can convert the price into txt but not integer

`SELECT price::integer FROM car`  gives me

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type integer

because of the dollar sign, can you advise me that way to solve the problem and make it a calculated price.

Comment: Show us your sample data. Show us your price column data type. Most likely, you will need to look for a dollar sign and replace it, then cast it to int.

Comment: [Don't use money](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money) - this is another example why you should avoid it

Comment: Can you share the definition of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, get rid of money. It is normally a bad idea to use it. If you really need to use it, cast it to `numeric` to apply your calculations:

```
SELECT price::numeric FROM car;
```

Note: `int` will truncate the decimals - not sure if you want that:

```
WITH car (price) AS (
  VALUES ('42,42€'::money),('75,50€'::money)
) SELECT avg(price::numeric) FROM car;
         avg         
---------------------
 58.9600000000000000
(1 row)
```